# Use the existing created neo4j graph for every server restart

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I have developed a web application with neo4j(py2neo), Flask and HTML. I am creating the Neo4j graph by reading the csv file. This CSV file size is larger. So whenever I start or restart the server Neo4j graph is getting created everytime and it takes lot of time for this setup. Is there anyway I can use the created graph and store it in my machine. So My project struture is I have models.py which contains connecting the graph, creating the graph with relations, and returns the data to routes.py.

My models.py looks like this

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship,NodeMatcher
import pandas as pd


class Query:
    "Model the tags"
    print("I am coming here")
    graph = Graph("http://blah:blah@127.0.0.1/db/data")
    print("hi i am second")
    
    try:
        graph.run("Match () Return 1 Limit 1")
        df=pd.read_csv("data.csv")
        print("I am not reading till")
        graph.delete_all()

        matcher = NodeMatcher(graph)
        row_count = len(df)      

        for i in range(row_count):            
            tags = df['tags'][i]
            each_tag = tags.split('|')
            tag_data = [x.lower() for x in each_tag]
            for j,first_tag in enumerate(tag_data[:-1]):
                match_first_tag = matcher.match("May21tag",tagName=first_tag).first()               
                graph.push(match_first_tag)
                for second_tag in tag_data[j+1:]:
                    my_tag = second_tag
                    second_tag = matcher.match("May21tag",tagName=second_tag).first()
                    graph.push(second_tag)                    
                    create_relationship = Relationship(match_first_tag ,"tagged",second_tag)
                    graph.merge(create_relationship)
    except Exception as e:
        print('not ok',e)

    def __init__(tech):
        tech_word = tech
        print("in init")

    def fetch_nodes(self,tech_word):
        graph = Graph("http://blah:blah@127.0.0.1/db/data")
        matcher = NodeMatcher(graph)
        match_nodes = matcher.match(tagName=tech_word).first()
        return (list(r.end_node["tagName"] for r in self.graph.match(nodes=(match_nodes,)).limit(6)))
```

So what is happening here is whenever I run the app.py I can see the graph and relationship are getting created everytime. So it takes time. WHat I need here is I wanted to use the existing graph with relations whenever I start or restart the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting everything in `Query` except the `__init__` and `fetch_nodes` method definitions.